# Native Resolution Unavailable for Second Monitor

Tags: resolution, multiple-monitors, kvm-switch

I am using this belkin switch: http://www.belkin.com/uk/switch2/

The switch basically connects 1 monitor to 2 different computers so you can easily switch output display between the computers. Right now, I am using it for my laptop (HP DV6500T) which uses 1280x800 resolution. My monitor (Viewsonic VA1912wb) is using the same resolution as my laptop, and I want to switch it to its native resolution (1440x900), but when I try to select it, its not available to pick. How can I use my monitors native resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a custom resolution in Nvidia control panel and then select the resolution.